# An efficient method to compute a minimum set of sets that form the union of these sets?

Tags: algorithms, sets

Let's say we have a set of sets:

$$\mathfrak S = \lbrace S_1, S_2, ... , S_n\rbrace$$

And the union of the all the sets in this set:

$$\mathfrak U = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} S_{i}$$

And so there is at least one minimum set of sets that is identical to this union:

$$(\mathfrak M \subseteq  \mathfrak S) = \mathfrak U$$

What is the most efficient known method of computing $\mathfrak M$ ?

Comment: What is the nature of these sets? Finite, countable, etc.? You probably mean the [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP-complete.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "...that is identical to this union"? Union of sets belonging to $\mathfrak M$?

Comment: @fade2black: thank you, the Set Cover problem is exactly what I meant

Comment: @fade2black Make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $S_i$ sets are finite your problem is reduced to the [Set Cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) which is NP-complete. You can also attack this problem by any approximation algorithm, e.g. Greedy algorithm, or by using Linear programming.